# How to keep remote script running when dropping ssh?

Tags: linux, mac, ssh, shell, remote-access

I `ssh` from my MacBook to a remote Linux and started a lengthy script (import 2000000+ lines of csv text records into MySQL). Too bad I have to take away my MacBook one hour later.

How can I keep the script running when I unplug my MacBook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nohup and run your process in the background.  Run your process like this:

`nohup command &`

Edit:
To nohup running processes: press ctrl+z, enter "bg" and enter "disown"

Comment: for my case, I have already started the script, is there something I can do _now_? Thanks

Comment: Found a solution on `nohup` wikipedia. To `nohup` running processes: press `ctrl+z`, enter `"bg"` and enter `"disown"`.

Answer (score 8):

nohup is fine, but spartian. screen is powerful. Let's do:

```
screen
command
```

type Control-A, then d. This will detach the screen session. You'll see the detached session with:

```
screen -ls
```

To reattach a session:

```
screen -r
```

See also [this screen presentation](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-gnu_screen/index.html?ca=dgr-lnxw07GNU-Screen&S_TACT=105AGX59&S_CMP=grsitelnxw07)