# How can I reconnect to a dropped gutil ssh session?

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, debian, osx-mavericks

I have installed Matlab on a (remote) linux (debian) machine. I run Matlab by tunnelling in from my Osx machine via ssh and then using the command line interface. To run a Matlab script I run

```
./matlab
```

then within the Matlab command line interface I cd to the local directory.

Once in the directory local to the Matlab script (matlabscript.m) I run

```
run('matlabscript.m')
```

This works as expected.

However if the ssh session drops during the running of said script the process terminates. I wish to run a rather long simulation (taking 6 days) and my ssh connections seem to be a bit shaky. Is there a way to:

1. Ensure the program keeps running the simulation whether or not the ssh connection is live
2. Breath new life into the old ssh conenction such that I go straight back into the Matlab interface (where regular updates are posted on progress of the matlabscript.m).

I've seen answers such as [Retry dropped ssh connections](https://superuser.com/questions/416467/retry-dropped-ssh-connections) and [How to keep remote script running when dropping ssh?](https://superuser.com/questions/198903/how-to-keep-remote-script-running-when-dropping-ssh?rq=1) however these don't address the particular usage of gcutil which as far as I'm aware is the only way of connecting to my linux instance in google compute engine.

Comment: Just posted under a different question: up vote 0 down vote
 

You might want to look at the 'screen' unix tool. It's a terminal "multiplexer" that opens multiple terminals over a single connection (ssh, telnet, or local). It's configurable to automatically open multiple shells or commands (eg. vim, top, etc) in different screens with a new connection. It can also preserve sessions across disconnects.

Answer (score 1):

After a little more digging I found that OSx comes with screen installed. Full details on how to use screen are available at https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/ssh/using-gnu-screen-to-manage-persistent-terminal-sessions

It's awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Yes screen is your friend! If you need X11 i suggest to use VNC.